# Ajax Parent Form Submit not working for Calendar

Tags: ajax

I have a popup calendar that is being called from the parent form. What I am wanting to happen is when the user clicks on the date after it updates parent form field it automatically submits the parent form (where certain date checks will happen upon refresh). Ive tried using Ajax and for some reason the calendar popup window closes after the selection is made but the parent form wont submit. Is there anything Im missing here?

Here is the ajax code in the actual calendar popup window.

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
// function create GetXmlHttpObject
function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
return new XMLHttpRequest();
}
if (window.ActiveXObject)
{
// code for IE6, IE5
return new ActiveXObject(“Microsoft.XMLHTTP”);
}
return null;
}

function submitFormWithAjax(){
var myAjaxPostrequest=new GetXmlHttpObject();

var t2lrequestend=document.docreq.request_end.value;
var t2lrsubmit="Submit Request";

var parameters=”request_end=”+t2lrequestend+"rsubmit="+t2lrsubmit;

myAjaxPostrequest.open(“POST”, “rm_new_arp_request_NEW_TIME_RESTRICTION.php”, true);
myAjaxPostrequest.setRequestHeader(“Content-type”, “application/x-www-form-urlencoded”);
myAjaxPostrequest.send(parameters);
myAjaxPostrequest.onreadystatechange=function(){
if(myAjaxPostrequest.readyState==4){
if(myAjaxPostrequest.status==200){
document.getElementById(“result”).innerHTML=myAjaxPostrequest.responseText;
document.getElementById(“docreq”).style.display = “none”;
}
else    {
document.getElementById(“docreq”).innerHTML=”An error has occured making the request”;
}
}
}
}

</script>
```

And here is where it is supposed to submit the form and close the child window.

```
function set_datetime(n_datetime, b_close) {
    if (!obj_caller) return;

    var dt_datetime = obj_caller.prs_time(
        (document.cal ? document.cal.time.value : ''),
        new Date(n_datetime)
    );

    if (!dt_datetime) return;
    if (b_close) {

        obj_caller.target.value = (document.cal
            ? obj_caller.gen_tsmp(dt_datetime)
            : obj_caller.gen_date(dt_datetime)
        );
        submitFormWithAjax();
        window.close();

    }
    else obj_caller.popup(dt_datetime.valueOf());
}

if (obj_caller && obj_caller.time_comp)
    document.write('<form onsubmit="javascript:set_datetime('+dt_current.valueOf()+', true)"><tr><td colspan="7" bgcolor="#87CEFA"><font color="White" face="tahoma, verdana" size="2">Time: <input type="text" name="request_end" value="'+obj_caller.gen_time(this.dt_current)+'" size="8" maxlength="8"><INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="rsubmit" VALUE="Submit Request" ></font></td></tr></form>');
</script>
</table></tr></td>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on how I can get this to submit the parent form with the date still being used?

Comment: Are you missing a `&` between the two parameters?

Comment: Sorry can you please elaborate on between which 2 parameters?

Comment: I think it should be `var parameters="request_end="+t2lrequestend+"&rsubmit="+t2lrsubmit;`. Also, there are some different quote characters in there...

Comment: Thanks for that, I added the & and also cleaned up all the quotes but it still does the same thing. Im guessing since its not actually closing the popup window that its failing on      submitFormWithAjax();